# Filter objects by self relation

Tags: django, django-models

Here is my Django model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Message', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    threads = ThreadManager()


class ThreadManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ThreadManager, self).get_queryset().filter()
```

As you see, it uses a custom manager. In `ThreadManager` I want to filter messages which has a self relation. I mean `parent` refers to its record. (`x.parent = x`)

How to write that `filter`? Is it possible at all?

Comment: With points to its record, you mean that `some_message.parent == some_message`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Yes exactly. (question edited)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Self reference

You can use a filter where you address the `pk` column:

```
from django.db.models import F

Message.objects.filter(parent=F('pk'))
```

So here we specify that the `parent_id` should be the same as the primary key, hence in that case the relation is cyclic.

Note that this filter will *not* detect cycles that have a length longer than 1. For example if we have two messages `A` and `B`, and `A.parent = B` and `B.parent = A`, then this filter will *not* detect this. It only detects `Message`s where `A.parent == A`.

Furthermore Django does *not* perform a semantical check: if you later let `parent` refer to another model, this filter does not makes much sense anymore, but Django will not produce a warning.

## Non self-referencing

In case we want to opposite, we can use `.exclude(..)` or wrap it into a `Q` object:

```
# using exclude
Message.objects.exclude(parent=F('pk'))

# using Q
from django.db.models import Q

Message.objects.filter(~Q(parent=F('pk')))
```

So in that case the `Message` either has no parent, or a parent that is not the same message.

Comment: Thanks, and what about it's opposite? I mean messages that `parent` is either `null` or refers to another object. With `Q` we have `~Q(....)` but what about `F`?